# How to add a small description window when mouse cursor is over a element class?

Tags: javascript

I tested a method for see if it works, but... no, see:

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName('avatarTestCx');

function myFunction() {
document.write("Test.");
}

for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
    classname[i].addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, false);
}
```

When the mouse cursor is about a element class, it calls a function to write in document (it's just a test to verify if will be possible do the small description window).

It's not working...

Do you have some method for example?

Comment: You have added a "click" listener, but you need a "mouseenter" listener

Comment: And you are executing [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) in the event handler, which will completely overwrite your entire page.

Comment: you can use `mouseover` listener and `alert("Test")` for getting description.

Comment: I think you want to show a tooltip on mouse over. Here is a nice javascript library for that:http://www.tippedjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a simple tooltip I guess a `title` attribute would get this done.
Here is a example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/542jwva8/1/

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName('avatarTestCx');
for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
    classname[i].setAttribute("title", "Small description \n Another line");
}
```

Comment: What does not work? On hovering over the text in fiddle there is a small window with the description displayed?

Comment: No. I think have no solution for this, I'm using links for test.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about doing this, by using `data-tooltip`

**Example**

Inside this example it'll show a message box when hovering over an element, any questions just ask me

```js
// Create style
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);

// Store matching elements
var matchingElements = [];

// All elements
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

// Loop through all elements
for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++) 
{
    // All elements with attribute of data-tooltip
    var attr = allElements[i].getAttribute('data-tooltip');
    if (attr) 
    {
        allElements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', hoverEvent);
    }
}

function hoverEvent(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    x = event.x - this.offsetLeft;
    y = event.y - this.offsetTop;

    // Show value of "this" inside console
    console.log(this);

    // Make it hang below the cursor a bit.
    y += 10;

    style.innerHTML = '*[data-tooltip]::after { left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px  }'

    // Show value of "this" inside console
    console.log(this);
}
```

```css
*[data-tooltip] {
    position: relative;
}

*[data-tooltip]::after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    width: 150px;
    
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background: #fefdcd;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

*[data-tooltip]:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* No need for this CSS, just for example purpose */
 div {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="Test message 1"></div>
<div data-tooltip="Test message 2"></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to add it, when I finish it, I will say the result or some ask. Thanks!